# Frequent GC when converting objects into JSON strings using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I wanted to convert object into a JSON string, but something unexpected happened.
This is my procedure.

```
    public class MainFragment extends BaseFragment<BeanEntity> {
      @Override protected int initLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
      }

      @Override public void initView(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.initView(view, savedInstanceState);

        /*
         *An unexpected situation occurred when I executed the following code
         */

        String s = new Gson().toJson(mCurrentUser);
        LogUtil.e(s);
      }
    }
```

[这是Android Studio的监视器图片。](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5AVg.png)

Comment: Maybe add the contents of the link here

Comment: If it is related to GCs, extract the `new Gson()` to a static final field to avoid creation on each iteration - it is thread-safe

Comment: I have fixed the error. The reason is that mCurrentUser is not a correct entity class